# Cosmos graph DB RU for Update operation using Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I have a graph DB and the requirement is to update an attribute in a few vertices. Now let's assume I have to update an attribute value from 0 to 1.

Approach #1 -
run update for each vertex in a loop

```
foreach(int id in ids) {
  g.V().has('vertex','key','test').has('id', id).Property('status','1')
}
```

RU utilized per query -

METRIC         | VALUE

Request Charge | 17.29

Approach #2 -
use a single Gremlin Query to update all vertex

```
g
  .V()
  .has('vertex','key','test')
  .has('id', within('1','2','3'))
  .Property('status','1')
```

METRIC         | VALUE

Request Charge | 41.4

Which approach is better considering the RUs and time taken to run the code?

Comment: Whichever requires less RU is what you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the query that consumes least amount of RUs, like @Mark Brown suggested. However, keep in mind that there will be gremlin query length limitations enforced by your client as well as by cosmos. cosmosDB gremlin API requires your query length to be less than `2^16 = 65536`. You may have to batch your request depending on the size of your `ids`

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1 (individual updates in a loop) is more efficient in terms of RUs (17.29) and time taken compared to Approach #2 (single query with within clause) which has higher RUs (41.4).

Comment: How did you determine that the one with less RU takes less time? The OP didn’t share any timing measurements. Also, aside from timing (which can’t be determined without benchmark data),  all you did here in your answer was reflect the OP’s RU stats.